# Java mutex.wait() and mutex.notify() timing issues? unexpected behaviour

Tags: java

Hi I have create the following small java class that wants to run a stock and there is a producer thread and a consumer thread.

The stock has a max CAPACITY (100) and it has a variable "stock" (meaning the current number of items in it).

```
package kapitel4;

public class StockNotifyWait {
    static final int CAPACITY = 100;
    static int stock = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var mutex_stock = new Object();
        var random = new java.util.Random();

        var producer = new Runnable () {
            @Override public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    synchronized (mutex_stock) {
                        while (stock == CAPACITY) {
                            System.out.println("producer waiting");
                            try {
                                mutex_stock.wait();
                            } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
                        }
                        int howmany = random.nextInt(CAPACITY - stock) + 1;
                        stock += howmany;
                        System.out.println("producing " + howmany + ", stock: " + stock);
                        mutex_stock.notify();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        var consumer = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    synchronized (mutex_stock) {
                        while (stock == 0) {
                            System.out.println("consumer waiting");
                            try {
                                mutex_stock.wait();
                            } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
                        }
                        int howmany = random.nextInt(stock) + 1;
                        stock -= howmany;
                        System.out.println("consuming " + howmany + ", stock: " + stock);
                        mutex_stock.notify();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        new Thread(producer).start();
        new Thread(consumer).start();
    }
}
```

Both producer and consumer are taking/putting a random number of the available/empty slots into the stock.

So the idea is, that if lager is full than the producer waits until the consumer at least takes 1 out. And then start producing again.

To the opposite if the lager is empty, consumer will wait until produced has at least produced 1 unit.

But instead of this behaviour I get this.

```
$ java kapitel4.StockNotifyWait 
producing 78, stock: 78
producing 20, stock: 98
producing 1, stock: 99
producing 1, stock: 100
producer waiting
consuming 70, stock: 30
consuming 27, stock: 3
consuming 1, stock: 2
consuming 1, stock: 1
consuming 1, stock: 0
consumer waiting
producing 38, stock: 38
producing 33, stock: 71
producing 5, stock: 76
producing 9, stock: 85
producing 3, stock: 88
producing 5, stock: 93
producing 3, stock: 96
producing 1, stock: 97
producing 2, stock: 99
producing 1, stock: 100
producer waiting
consuming 15, stock: 85
consuming 26, stock: 59
consuming 7, stock: 52
consuming 6, stock: 46
consuming 3, stock: 43
consuming 20, stock: 23
consuming 12, stock: 11
consuming 5, stock: 6
consuming 5, stock: 1
consuming 1, stock: 0
consumer waiting
producing 18, stock: 18
producing 12, stock: 30
producing 7, stock: 37
producing 36, stock: 73
producing 11, stock: 84
producing 2, stock: 86
producing 3, stock: 89
producing 7, stock: 96
producing 3, stock: 99
producing 1, stock: 100
producer waiting
consuming 32, stock: 68
consuming 33, stock: 35
consuming 8, stock: 27
consuming 2, stock: 25
consuming 5, stock: 20
consuming 15, stock: 5
consuming 4, stock: 1
consuming 1, stock: 0
consumer waiting
producing 83, stock: 83
producing 7, stock: 90
producing 9, stock: 99
producing 1, stock: 100
producer waiting
consuming 31, stock: 69
consuming 19, stock: 50
consuming 40, stock: 10
consuming 9, stock: 1
consuming 1, stock: 0
consumer waiting
producing 17, stock: 17
producing 39, stock: 56
producing 25, stock: 81
producing 5, stock: 86
producing 10, stock: 96
producing 2, stock: 98
producing 1, stock: 99
producing 1, stock: 100
producer waiting
consuming 71, stock: 29
consuming 20, stock: 9
consuming 2, stock: 7
consuming 2, stock: 5
consuming 4, stock: 1
consuming 1, stock: 0
consumer waiting
producing 13, stock: 13
producing 45, stock: 58
producing 3, stock: 61
producing 37, stock: 98
producing 1, stock: 99
producing 1, stock: 100
producer waiting
consuming 85, stock: 15
consuming 12, stock: 3
consuming 3, stock: 0
consumer waiting
producing 32, stock: 32
producing 2, stock: 34
producing 48, stock: 82
producing 13, stock: 95
producing 4, stock: 99
producing 1, stock: 100
producer waiting
consuming 9, stock: 91
consuming 58, stock: 33
consuming 7, stock: 26
consuming 13, stock: 13
consuming 9, stock: 4
consuming 3, stock: 1
consuming 1, stock: 0
consumer waiting
```

It looks ike the producer is waiting until the consumer has fully emptied the stock before it starts producing again, and same for the consumer. It waits until the producer has filled the stack before it starting to consume again.

If i put the threads to sleep, it looks better

(I added to both threads after the synchronize block):

```
                   try {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
```

then this looks better.

```
consuming 12, stock: 65
consuming 10, stock: 55
producing 17, stock: 72
producing 11, stock: 83
consuming 54, stock: 29
consuming 12, stock: 17
producing 35, stock: 52
producing 10, stock: 62
consuming 54, stock: 8
consuming 2, stock: 6
producing 35, stock: 41
consuming 9, stock: 32
producing 26, stock: 58
consuming 10, stock: 48
producing 52, stock: 100
producer waiting
consuming 82, stock: 18
producing 33, stock: 51
consuming 26, stock: 25
producing 67, stock: 92
consuming 5, stock: 87
producing 9, stock: 96
consuming 79, stock: 17
producing 22, stock: 39
consuming 8, stock: 31
```

So is that actually the notify and wait are taking to long, so that the producer (without wait) has already filled the stack before the consumer is even receiving the notification?

Comment: Try replacing `notify()` by `notifyAll()` in both runnables

Comment: @user16320675 my main issue is that it looks like it is waiting until stock is full/empty. But that is just because it is so fast, that the notify will take longer to activate the thread.

So I think this is just visualization here and a Thread.sleep(5) does already resolve it. Then you can see that it works as intended.

Comment: This is totally valid behaviour for this code. There’s nothing that requires the lock to be shared fairly between the two threads. Certain JVM optimizations might be part of the reason this happens (https://shipilev.net/jvm/anatomy-quarks/1-lock-coarsening-for-loops/). In more realistic code, there will generally be some I/O happening outside of the synchronized block that would give the other thread an opportunity to run.

Comment: Given that there is in this code only 0 or 1 threads waiting on a notification, @DuncG's advice of using `notifyAll()` is useless. It has no bearing on the question or the snippet.

Comment: Agreed, note that change in behaviour can be seen simply by adding`Thread.currentThread(). yield()` or moving the `System.out.println()` outside synchronized blocks.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: What you are observing is [A] legal, and [B] actually because threads work faster than you think, not slower than you think. [C] The example you created is not good. It has fundamental flaws that result in you drawing the wrong conclusion.

---

To fully explain this, we need LOTS of context.

### The ebb and flow of `wait`/`notify` systems

The behaviour you are observing is, as per the spec, legal. `notify()` is not the problem: Given that when you fire off that notify, only exactly one thread is at that moment `wait()`ing on that object, it HAS to wake up. So it does - but the way all notify/wait systems work, given that you must be in `synchronized (x)` when you invoke either `x.wait()` or `x.notify()`, is this:

- The `wait()` method wants to end now, given that it has been notified. So it does, but it cannot actually return until that thread re-acquires the lock on `x`. After all, the code we are trying to now continue with is *within* a `synchronized (x)` block. `wait` first relinquishes that lock, then waits for a notify, then reacquires it, then returns. Thus, notifying it moves it from the 'waiting for the notify state' to the 'waiting to reacquire the lock' state.
- This will *neccessarily* fail - after all, the code that just called `x.notify()` still has it! That means the thread that was just woken up with `notify()` is immediately going to resort to 'wait around until we can acquire the lock on `x`'. It doesn't actually wake up *at all* to do any of this, it's just internal bookkeeping by the scheduler all done on the 'dime' of the notifying thread. You aren't losing CPU cycles. Point is, notify() doesn't actually immediately wake anything up. The combination of notifying **and** ending the `synchronized` block that the `x.notify()` call was in, *that* potentially wakes up something else.
- In the mean time the notifying thread runs to its end, exits its synchronized block, hits the while loop and immediately re-enters it, and the first line in the while block is.. re-acquiring the lock. So, whilst in theory at the exact point it exits, the other thread is now free to acquire the lock on `x` and start, this thread doesn't stop what its doing whilst all that is happening (you seem to think threads are too slow. Now, they are **faster** than you think they are - the consumer gets through its while loop and hits its `synchronized` faster than you think - effectively instantaneously).
- Hence we have now arrived at a contention: Both the producer and the consumer want to reacquire the lock *at the same time*.
- The `synchronized` specs are quite explicit about this: *They are not guaranteed to be fair* - there is no 'oh well the consumer most recently held this lock so it is more fair to give the lock to the producer as it was waiting longer' mechanism happening here. Instead the system flips an evil coin. ('coin' is in, either one COULD win, 'evil' as in, it doesn't do what you want, nor does it follow any material guideline such as '50% of the time it picks one, 50% of the time the other' - instead it might pick the consumer 999999 out of 1000000 times, but on another system it picks the producer far more often. Or it picks the consumer every time, except the one day you are giving an important demo, then it picks the consumer. If your code depends on any particular selection behaviour about which of 2 contenders 'wins' the battle, your code is by definition therefore broken. In an untestable way.
- This is merely *what usually happens*, given that as per spec anything can happen, but, on *most* systems the notifying thread wins that battle almost always. It's still running, after all.

With all that context it should now be clear that what you observe is technically perfectly legal and not indicative that things could have been done any faster (it is, as far as the code and the CPU is concerned, not inherently faster to go 'produce something, consume something, produce something' than to go 'produce something, produce something, consume something'). It could be considered 'more fair' to alternate producing and consuming but adding fairness is very expensive and hard to define, so most systems instead explicitly say that no fairness is guaranteed, and if you need fairness, you write code to establish it.

And it isn't slow! That's because in this example, there is effectively zero time in between holding the lock: Given the code you pasted, one core is all you're ever going to end up using. That's because due to the way things are set up, there is nothing for the system to do outside of the stuff that is in `synchronized` blocks.

In normal, non-academic cases, your producer and your consumer don't work like that. The producer takes some time to produce a value and does this **outside** of any lock. It then acquires the lock (or waits to do so if need be) to 'provide' what it produced to the queue. The consumer is the same way: It locks to obtain an item from the queue, but once it has that item, it consumes it outside of the lock and takes some time to do so.

Had this snippet worked like that you'd see the benefits of your multithreaded approach: Most of the time both threads are active - with threads sleeping only in rare cases where they both finish their main jobs (consuming resp. producing) at the same time and thus they need to one-at-a-time go through the queue, or, of course, when there is nothing for them to do (e.g. if the producer produces faster than the consumer can consume, the producer will often be frozen. And vice versa. That's intentional, of course).

### Better primitives

More generally this is an *extremely* common concept (producers that add to a queue, consumers that consume from it), and because of that, you shouldn't be using wait/notify for this. Have a look through the `j.u.concurrent` package, it has loads of nice stuff for this. Specifically, the [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) which has much better primitives. The producer simply calls `.put(elem)`, which will block if the queue is full. The consumer calls `take()` which will block if the queue is empty. And no `synchronized`, `wait`, or `notify` needs to be written anywhere. Just works.

### So why does `Thread.sleep` fix things?

Because with the sleep you are emulating 'the act of producing / consuming' is a non-instantaneous job.

### A warning about multicore experimentation

Normally, 'just play around, you learn more that way' is great. **But not here**.

The problem is that evil coin, which is all over multicore. It comes up with lock contention, sure, but also with memory synchronization: *If ever you read a field from 2 threads you have broken code* - unless you can explicitly ascertain that proper Happens-Before relationships have been established. And here, too, we have the evil coin:

```
// initial condition:
fieldA = 0;
fieldB = 0;

// writer:
fieldA = 1;
fieldB = 2;

// reader:
System.out.println(fieldA);
System.out.println(fieldB);
```

In the above code, assuming writer and reader run simultaneously and have no HB establishing code in it, reader can legally print '0/0', '0/2', '1/0', and '1/2'. Yes, '0/2' would be out-of-order observation: The write to fieldA isn't 'seen' but the write to fieldB **is** seen. **This is legal**.

However, not all JVMs use this. For example, it's more likely on ARM chips than on intel chips. Herein lies in inherent problem when using experimentation to figure out how it all works: Your experiments lead you to draw the wrong conclusion, and you end up writing code that works great right now but won't work on my machine, or won't work tomorrow, or won't work when that song on your music player switches over to another.

Also, synchronization limits sneak in, in the weirdest places. For example, `System.out.println` is generally synchronized - and is incredibly slow relative to CPU operations, so, often causes a pre-emption. It is often treated as ignorable 'just logging stuff so I can see what happens, nothing to see here' interjections that you don't even think about when reasoning about threading, but, that is precisely wrong: It is likely dominating the locking and thread switching behaviour!

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. The major issue with all of that is, that this is actually out of a University course, where this is an example on how mutex works.
This is actually a pretty bad example then.